# What if two RDDs depend on the another RDD spark

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

If two RDDs RDD1 and RDD2, both depend on RDD3, and RDD1 to 3 is shuffle denpendency, RDD2 to 3 is narrow dependency, then how the stage is created, will RDD3 be in two stages?